# Django super __init__ causing m2m form to not validate

Tags: django, django-forms, django-orm

I have a form that handles m2m request in the validation.

my form looks as follows

```
class HuntingReportForm(ModelForm):
    date_travel_started = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1970,2010)))
    date_travel_ended = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1970,2010)))
    wish_list = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Specie.objects.all(), widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("verbose name", is_stacked=False), required=False)
    bag_list = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Trophies.objects.all(), widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("verbose name", is_stacked=False), required=False)

class Meta:
    model = HuntingReport
    exclude = ['user',]

def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    self.validate = kwargs.pop('validate',False)
    super(HuntingReportForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    users = User.objects.filter(userprofile__outfitter=True)
    self.fields['outfitter'].choices = [('', '')] + [(user.pk, user.get_full_name()) for user in users]
    self.fields.keyOrder = ['title', 'report', 'date_travel_started', 'date_travel_ended', 'wish_list', 'bag_list', 'outfitter']
```

When I remove the whole `def __init__` section the forms seems to validate and save, however with the following code it just keep throwing me back to the page saying that some fields weren't filled in, even when they were.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the view, but presumably you're instantiating the form with the usual `form = HuntingReportForm(request.POST)`. Unfortunately, you've changed the signature of the form's `__init__` method to expect `user` as the first positional argument, so the data isn't being passed in. You should move `user` to kwargs and treat it the same as your `validate` argument:

```
def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    self.validate = kwargs.pop('validate', False)
    super(HuntingReportForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out and let you know the result